# How can I switch to a tab to another ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twig

I have two tabs 
[image]

And I need to switch to the "VOTRE SÉLECTION", erase the content of "NOTRE SELECTION DU MOMENT" and display other contents instead.

I know it's some basic AJAX but I am a backend dev and I do not have time to learn this right now :(

This is the code :

```
{{ include('_tabs.html.twig') }}
<section class="list">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="item-container">
            {% if isAmiral %}
                {% if (distance < 400 and distance > 200) or isParis %}
                    {{ blocks.home_selection_200_450km_idf|raw }}
                {% elseif distance < 200 %}
                    {{ blocks.home_selection_proximite|raw }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ blocks.selection|raw }}
                {% endif %}
            {% else %}
                {{ blocks.selection|raw }}
            {% endif %}
            {# CLEAR #}
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-btn">
            <a href="{{ rewrite_path(highlightmenu, {locale: app.request.locale}) }}">{{ 'button.all_highlights'|trans }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and tabs.html contains this :

```
<section class="tabs-container full-image mode-{{ context }}">

    {% if (context == 'amiral') %}
        <nav class="tabs amiral">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="tab amiral-A"><a href="" class="tab-btn amiral-btn-A">{{ 'label.our_selection'|trans }}</a></li><!--
             --><li class="tab amiral-B selected"><a href="" class="tab-btn amiral-btn-B">{{ 'label.your_selection'|trans }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    {% elseif (context == 'sejour') %}
        <nav class="tabs sejour A-selected">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="tab sejour-A selected"><a href="" class="tab-btn sejour-btn-A">{{ 'label.favorites'|trans }}</a></li><!--
             --><li class="tab sejour-B"><a href="" class="tab-btn sejour-btn-B">{{ 'link.account_wishlist'|trans }}</a></li><!--
             --><li class="tab sejour-C"><a href="" class="tab-btn sejour-btn-C">{{ 'label.around'|trans }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    {% endif %}

</section>
```

JS :

```
if ($('.tabs.amiral').length == 1) {
    $('.tab-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).find('nav.tabs .tab').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    });
}
```

To make this more clear, I need to do somethink like this :

```
{% if VOTRE_SELECTION %}
    {{ display_block_a }}
{% else %}
    {{ display_block_B }}
```

So what do I need to add to make this work ?

Comment: You simply have to switch the `A-selected` class over in your `tabs.html`, your CSS rules should take care of displaying and hiding the right tab.

Comment: This work already,

  $(document).find('nav.tabs .tab').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).parent().addClass('selected');

 Now I need to switch my content in function of my active tab.

Comment: If all your content is there you can simply display one tab and hide the other. If content needs to be fetched, checkout jquery's `load` method for easy ajax.

Comment: Also, because you are using some template code, it is hard to build an example, and it all depends on the way you have set it up. For example, if you want to load the content dynamically, you should be able to use `jquery.load()`, but you need to load _only_ those contents. Best way is to print both tabs and use javascript to switch them and CSS to hide/display them.